# How to get a column value of item in ListView when I use CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE mode and ArrayAdapter<String>?

Tags: android

I hope to use `String aa=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"))` to get the column value of a item in the function `private void SetSelectedAndTotal`.
but the app crash, how can I do? Thanks!

```
private ListView lv; 
private TextView selectedAndTotal;

private void InitListView() {
    List<String> msgList = getSMS();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, msgList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            SetSelectedAndTotal(arg2);
        }
    });
}

private void SetSelectedAndTotal(int arg2){     
    Cursor c = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    String aa=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
    selectedAndTotal.setText(aa);       
}


public List<String> getSMS() {
    List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
            null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);

    }
    return sms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String aa=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
selectedAndTotal.setText(aa);
```

if no such column exists, this returns `-1`. Most probably, this happens and you are passing an integer as argument which is considered a resource ID.

Also, make sure you initialized `TextView` before you `setText()`.

Comment: The code I pasted is only part, I have initialize selectedAndTotal

Comment: I think Cursor c = (Cursor) lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2) cause error.
I don't know how to write code to get a column value